# Experimenting `for...of` and `for...in` with `iterator` and `iterable`

Tags: javascript

From the output of following snippets, I can conclude the following. But not sure if they are correct or not.

i) `for...of` can be used both for `iterable` and `iterator` 
 
ii)`for...in` can only used for `iterable` and not for `iterator`

```
    var array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
    var iterator = array1.keys(); 

    for (let key of iterator) {
      console.log(key); // 0 1 2
    }
    for (let value of array1) {
      console.log(value); // 'a' 'b' 'c'
    }
    for (var index in array1) {
      console.log(array1[index]); // 'a' 'b' 'c'
    }
    for (var key in iterator) {
      console.log(key); // `Not executed`
    }
```

Comment: FYI - `array1.keys()` is `{}`

Comment: Or, you could just read the docs - [for ... in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), [for ... of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of). Also relevant but immediately linked there, [iterable protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#The_iterable_protocol)

Comment: `for … in` can only be used on *enumerable* objects. It has nothing to do with iterators/iterables. (It's just that in your example, the array has some enumerable properties while the iterator has not. In any case, [don't use `for…in` enumerations on arrays!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572))

Comment: Notice that all iterators are iterable by simply returning themselves from `[Symbol.iterator]()`. `for of` always works on iterables.